# Calling typescript compiler from java program

Tags: javascript, typescript, compiler-construction

I am writing a Java program which will emit Typescript code based on a specification provided to it. Is there way for me to compile emitted typescript code to Javascript from within the java program.

Comment: Have you tried to write your file into your nodejs project and execute bash from your java program ?

Comment: Another option for duplication: [Calling a node.js script from inside java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275479/calling-a-node-js-script-from-inside-java)