# Does any "Export as war" package exist in npmjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, war

I'm looking for a package which would help me in exporting my project as a war file. However I don't see any relevant package in npmjs.com or anywhere else.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Explored npmjs.com for this package, and found none.
- Explored github and found none there as well.
- One SO solution suggested to make use of the `jar` command which
  unfortunately doesn't exist in my environment, I can't download and
  use it too due to restrictions.

Did anyone come across such module (or) any other solutions with respect to this? Can some one help?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, a WAR file is specific to a Java environment. If you are using nodeJS and Javascript, you are not using Java and the WAR format is not appropriate for your code...

What do you want to achieve with a war file more than something else?

> In computing, a WAR file (short for Web ARchive) could be a JAR file
>   used to distribute a collection of JavaServer Pages, servlets, Java
>   classes, XML files, tag libraries and static Web pages (HTML and
>   related files) that together constitute a Web application.
>
> **Wikipedia**

EDIT: The only solution I see would be to create a Java Application that would eventually require and execute your nodeJS code... But this seems Hacky as hell. You can read this response about how to execute NodeJS code into a Java environment: [Calling a node.js script from inside java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275479/calling-a-node-js-script-from-inside-java)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!. We need to do some automation for which we need a way to run this export as war as a command. Looking for an option to achieve this..

Comment: I added some solution that consists of wrapping the node app into a java app, but... This is not how it is supposed to work..

Comment: At one job I was tasked with implementing a php interpreter inside a Java 'container' so that we could run some backend API on an Android-based smart-TV. So +1 for "this is not how it's supposed to work." Your description as "hackey as hell" is technically correct (the best kind of correct ;)).