# From Springboot app, invoke nodejs script and pass java object to the script, in script modify and return back object to calling class

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, spring-boot

```
Is there a way in java (Springboot app) 
- to invoke NodeJs script file, 
- pass java object to the script and modify that object in the js script. 
- And return back the modified object
```

for example as below.

```
class Services
{
    Address address = new Address(....);

    /*
    invoke NodeJs script and pass address object

    in the js script modify address object
    var address = getAddress()
    modify address object
    return address object back to java calling class
    setResultObject(address) or return address;
    */

    address = invokeJS("nameOfScriptWithLocation", address);
    System.out.println("modified address" + address.toString()
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a node.js script from inside java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275479/calling-a-node-js-script-from-inside-java)

Answer (score 1):

I know there are two ways to call node.js code in java.
First if you have the node js environment in your target server,you can use the command line to do it.
Follow is a simple example if that you hava a script named "script.js"

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("node", "script.js","name=jack");
Process process = pb.start();

InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

The second method is to use some tripartite class library to invoke the js code.
Just like graal js, J2V8,etc.